# Hide/Show em divs de acordo com subclasses

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou tentando fazer um código que mostre e esconda algumas divs no click, tentei usar css pra me ajudar, só que não consegui. Pela lógica a baixo no click do "topic" ele remove a classe exibir de todos os itens, e adiciona ao item clicado a classe exibir, então no css por ter a classe `entrega.topic.exibir .conteudo1` com `display:block;` era para mostrar esse conteúdo não? Ou estou fazendo algo errado.

**html**

```
<section class="central">
   <nav>
      <ul>
          <li><a class="icon-entrega"><span class="icon ic entrega topic"><p>Entregas</p></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="icon-gift"><span class="icon ic icon-gift topic"><p>Compras</p></span></a></li>
          <li><a class="icon-prod-flor"><span class="icon ic prod-flor topic"><p>Produtos</p></span></a></li>
          <li> <a class="icon-lock"><span class="icon ic lock topic"><p>Segurança</p></span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</section>

<section class="blc-ca">
   <div class="conteudo1"></div>
   <div class="conteudo2"></div>
   <div class="conteudo3"></div>
   <div class="conteudo4"></div>
</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $j(document).on('click','.topic',function(){
    $j('.topic').removeClass('exibir');
    $j(this).addClass('exibir');
});
```

**Css**

```
section.blc-ca div {
display:none;
}

.entrega.topic.exibir .conteudo1 {
display: block;
}

.icon-gift.topic.exibir .conteudo2 {
display: block;
}

.prod-flor.topic.exibir .conteudo3 {
display: block;
}

.lock.topic.exibir .conteudo4 {
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que está a tentar aplicar a classe `exibir` aos `topic`s, quando os que quer mostrar são os `<div>` `conteudo` que não tem a classe `topic`. No entanto o *Jquery* já fornece funções bem simples para mostrar ou esconder elementos, que são o [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) e [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) respetivamente.

Utilizando essas podia fazer assim:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.topic', function() {
  let posicao = $(this).index(".topic"); //descobrir a posição do tópico clicado
  $('.blc-ca div').hide(); //esconder todos os conteudos
  $('.blc-ca .conteudo' + (posicao+1)).show(); //mostrar o correspondente ao clicado
});
```

```css
section.blc-ca div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="central">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="icon-entrega"><span class="icon ic entrega topic"><p>Entregas</p></span></a></li>
      <li><a class="icon-gift"><span class="icon ic icon-gift topic"><p>Compras</p></span></a></li>
      <li><a class="icon-prod-flor"><span class="icon ic prod-flor topic"><p>Produtos</p></span></a></li>
      <li> <a class="icon-lock"><span class="icon ic lock topic"><p>Segurança</p></span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>

<section class="blc-ca">
  <div class="conteudo1">conteudo div1</div>
  <div class="conteudo2">conteudo div2</div>
  <div class="conteudo3">conteudo div3</div>
  <div class="conteudo4">conteudo div4</div>
</section>
```

Repare que nem a classe `exibir` foi necessária, que por sinal também não tinha colocado na pergunta.

Comment: Sim, obrigado. Não havia pensado nessa solução

Answer (score 3):

Poderia fazer assim..

```js
$('nav ul li').on('click', function(){
  var div = $(this).attr('data-div')

  $('.blc-ca div').addClass('hidden')
  $('.'+div).removeClass('hidden')
})
```

```css
.hidden{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <section class="central">
   <nav>
      <ul>
          <li data-div="conteudo1"><a class="icon-entrega"><span class="icon ic entrega topic"><p>Entregas</p></span></a></li>
          <li data-div="conteudo2"><a class="icon-gift"><span class="icon ic icon-gift topic"><p>Compras</p></span></a></li>
          <li data-div="conteudo3"><a class="icon-prod-flor"><span class="icon ic prod-flor topic"><p>Produtos</p></span></a></li>
          <li data-div="conteudo4"> <a class="icon-lock"><span class="icon ic lock topic"><p>Segurança</p></span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</section>

<section class="blc-ca">
   <div class="conteudo1">1</div>
   <div class="conteudo2 hidden">2</div>
   <div class="conteudo3 hidden">3</div>
   <div class="conteudo4 hidden">4</div>
</section>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A sua está correta também, funciona e tudo mais, só que o @Isac respondeu com explicação e tudo mais, mas obrigado!